# In C#/.NET why is sbyte[] the same as byte[] except that it's not?

Tags: c#

I just observed a weird phenomenon in C#/.NET.

I created this minimal example to demonstrate:

```
if (new sbyte[5] is byte[])
{
 throw new ApplicationException("Impossible!");
}

object o = new sbyte[5];

if (o is byte[])
{
 throw new ApplicationException("Why???");
}
```

This will throw "Why???", but not "Impossible!". It works for all arrays of integral types of the same size. Can someone explain this to me? I'm confused. I'm using .NET 4 by the way.

P.S.: I know that I can get the expected result by using `o.GetType() == typeof(byte[])`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The CLR rules of casting specify that this is possible. The C# rules say it is not possible. [The C# team consciously decided](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/24/why-is-covariance-of-value-typed-arrays-inconsistent.aspx) that they would tolerate this deviation from the spec for various reasons.

Why does the CLR allow this? Probably because they can conveniently implement it. `byte` and `sbyte` have the same binary representation so you can "treat" a `byte[]` as an `sbyte[]` **without violating memory safety**.

The same trick works for other primitive types with the same memory layout.

Comment: You should include the fact that this deviation is isolated to value typed arrays.

Comment: It works for ref types, too (array co/contravariance). Ref typed arrays have runtime checks though. I quote Eric: One of the rules of the CLI is "if X is assignment compatible with Y then X[] is assignment compatible with Y[]".

Comment: The deviation is only for value types.  Replace `sbyte` with `string`, and `byte` with 'object'.  The code throws at "Impossible!".

Comment: BTW: why does e.g. `Array.Copy` throw an `ArrayTypeMismatchException` when I try to copy from `(byte[])o` to a real `byte[]` if the CLR rules say that the cast is possible?? I didn't think the implementation of `Array` was C#-specific...

Comment: I think the whole Microsoft toolchain is inconsistent around this issue because it has so little visibility. Doesn't matter much in practice, though.

Answer (score 28):

Funny, I got bitten by that in my question, [Why does this Linq Cast Fail when using ToList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039479/why-does-this-linq-cast-fail-when-using-tolist)

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (of course) explains that my problem is the C# compiler, for whatever reason, thinks they could never be the same thing, and helpfully optimizes it to false. However, the CLR *does* let this happen. The cast to object throws off the compiler optimization, so it goes through the CLR.

The relevant part from [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11039703/492405):

> Even though in C# you can't cast a byte[] to an sbyte[] directly, the CLR allows it:

```
var foo = new byte[] {246, 127};
// This produces a warning at compile-time, and the C# compiler "optimizes"
// to the constant "false"
Console.WriteLine(foo is sbyte[]);

object x = foo;
// Using object fools the C# compiler into really consulting the CLR... which
// allows the conversion, so this prints True
Console.WriteLine(x is sbyte[]);
```

---

Joel asked an interesting question in the comments, "Is this behavior controlled by the Optimize Code flag (`/o` to the compiler)?"

Given this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    sbyte[] baz = new sbyte[0];
    Console.WriteLine(baz is byte[]);
}
```

And compiled with `csc /o- Code.cs` (don't optimize), it appears that the compiler optimizes it anyway. The resulting IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0002:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.SByte
IL_0007:  stloc.0
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0009:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(bool)
IL_000e:  nop
IL_000f:  ret
```

IL_0008 loads 0 (false) directly onto the stack, then calls `WriteLine` on IL_0009. So no, the optimization flag does not make a difference. If the CLR were to be consulted, the `isinst` instruction would get used. It would probably look something like this starting from IL_0008:

```
IL_0008:  ldloc.0
IL_0009:  isinst     uint8[]
IL_000e:  ldnull
IL_000f:  cgt.un
IL_0011:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(bool)
```

I would agree with the optimizer's behavior. The optimization flag should not change the behavior of your program.

Comment: Does this mean that by changing compiler settings, you could get the "optimizes it to false" part to not happen?

Comment: The accepted answer does not attempt to explain why the two supposedly identical if statements behave differently as this one does.

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET actually "throws" at *compile* time:

> Expression of type '1-dimensional array of SByte' can never be of type '1-dimensional array of Byte'.

on the equivalent of the first `if` statement.

And the equivalent of the second `if` succeeds (i.e. it throws the coded exception) at runtime as expected because it is the same CLR.

Comment: Interesting. C# will emit a warning, so it's possible that if you use "treat warnings as errors" in C# then you can get the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler example that shows the same issue:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool a = ((object) new byte[0]) is sbyte[];
    bool b = (new byte[0]) is sbyte[];

    Console.WriteLine(a == b); // False
}
```

The inconsistency arises because the C# compiler decides that it knows the result of `(new byte[0]) is sbyte[]` at compile time, and just substitutes `false`. Perhaps it should really substitute `true`, to be more consistent with the CLR behaviour.

As far as I can tell, it's only this little optimization that's inconsistent. It occurs only when both sides of the `is` expression are statically typed as an array whose element type is a signed or unsigned integer or an enum, and the sizes of the integers are the same.

The good news is that while this might seem inconsistent, C# will always issue a warning when it substitutes `false` into such expressions – in practice, I think this might be more useful than quietly returning `true`.